# Weird getters from vuex. Can someone explain to me this behavior?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Ok i know that in js a lot of things looks like impossible or weird. But why implement them in product that use millions of ppl ?

here we have a function in getters

```
export const isAuthenticated = state => (
      state.auth !== null &&
      state.auth.access_token !== null &&
      new Date(state.auth.access_token_expiration) > new Date() 
      );
```

so if this is a function then we should call it with parentheses and 1 argument like `getters.isAuthenticated(state)` but this is not the case in getters - `getters.isAuthenticated` - no parentheses, no arguments it's just like property but is a function call. And if we do this `getters.isAuthenticated(arg)` then our function should look like `(state)=>(arg)=>{}`. 
Why is that ?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use getter as a function as written [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access). This is why you see `(state)=>(arg)=>{}`. Getters are alike `computed` properties, which are general javascript getters. Please, check the console in this simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wx2tenmh/2/). You will see these props set to the instance:
[image]

These are basic JS getter functions, nothing weird. If you want to know more, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) MDN reference. Hope this helps, have fun learning Vue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a variation of higher order functions, where your function (with state parameter) is replaced with another function (with no parameter) which when invoked calls your function and supplies the state parameter from it's own context.

From the source code [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js), I simplified the wrapper code from lines 303 & 425

```js
module.forEachGetter((rawGetter, key) => {
  store._wrappedGetters[key] = function wrappedGetter (store) {
    return rawGetter(
      local.state, // local state
      local.getters, // local getters
      store.state, // root state
      store.getters // root getters
    )
  }
})
```

At line 233 you can see the wrappedGetters being added to the store.getters property as [javascript getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and supplied with the store parameter. Again this is simplified, since the getters are added as computed properties to take advantage of value caching.

```js
forEachValue(wrappedGetters, (fn, key) => {
  Object.defineProperty(store.getters, key, {
    get: () => fn(store),
    enumerable: true // for local getters
  })
})
```